# Converting CDF of histogram to c# from matlab?

Tags: c#, matlab, histogram, aforge, cdf

How can I convert this matlab code to AForge.net+c# code?

```
cdf1 = cumsum(hist1) / numel(aa);
```

I found that there is Histogram.cumulative method is present in Accord.net.
But I dont know how to use.

Please teaching how to convert.

```
% Histogram Matching
%

clear
clc
close all

pkg load image

% 이미지 로딩
aa=imread('2.bmp');
ref=imread('ref2.png');

figure(1); imshow(aa); colormap(gray)
figure(2); imshow(ref); colormap(gray)

M = zeros(256,1,'uint8'); % Store mapping - Cast to uint8 to respect data type
hist1 = imhist(aa); % Compute histograms
hist2 = imhist(ref);

cdf1 = cumsum(hist1) / numel(aa); % Compute CDFs
cdf2 = cumsum(hist2) / numel(ref);

% Compute the mapping
for idx = 1 : 256
[~,ind] = min(abs(cdf1(idx) - cdf2));


M(idx) = ind-1;
end

% Now apply the mapping to get first image to make
% the image look like the distribution of the second image
out = M(double(aa)+1);

figure(3); imshow(out); colormap(gray)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I don't have a great knowledge of `Accord.NET`, but reading the documentation I think that `ImageStatistics` class is what you are looking for ([reference here](http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/T_Accord_Imaging_ImageStatistics.htm)). The problem is that it cannot build a single histogram for the image and you have to do it by yourself. `imhist` in Matlab just merges the three channels and then counts the overall pixel occurrences so this is what you should do:

```
Bitmap image = new Bitmap(@"C:\Path\To\Image.bmp");

ImageStatistics statistics = new ImageStatistics(image);
Double imagePixels = (Double)statistics.PixelsCount;

Int32[] histR = statistics.Red.Values.ToArray();
Int32[] histG = statistics.Green.Values.ToArray();
Int32[] histB = statistics.Blue.Values.ToArray();
Int32[] histImage = new Int32[256];

for (Int32 i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
    histImage[i] = histR[i] + histG[i] + histB[i];

Double cdf = new Double[256];
cdf[0] = (Double)histImage[0];

for (Int32 i = 1; i < 256; ++i)
    cdf[i] = (Double)(cdf[i] + cdf[i - 1]);

for (Int32 i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
    cdf[i] = cdf[i] / imagePixels;
```

In `C#`, an `RGB` value can be built from `R`, `G` and `B` channel values as follows:

```
public static int ChannelsToRGB(Int32 red, Int32 green, Int32 blue)
{
    return ((red << 0) | (green << 8) | (blue << 16));
}
```

Comment: I edited my answer and I was able to build an overall histogram with an overall cdf of the image. If this works, please remember to mark my answer as accepted.

Comment: Thanks @Tommaso, is it possible to convert the rest of the code?

Comment: Well I would like to, but this is not the proper place to ask for this. I gave you the basis, I'm pretty sure you can manage to complete it with some effort.

Comment: OK, I see. Thanks~